# PHP - Parse XML contained within XML element and Output into XML doc

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml

I'm looking to parse out only the content of the  element below into its own XML document, but am unsure of the proper PHP method to use. XML data in boxb.php is unable to be modified.

EX:
Parsing code:

```
<?php
include 'boxb.php';
$boxb = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
$boxb->ad[0]->content;
echo $boxb->ad[0]->content;
?>
```

boxb.php contains the following:

```
<?php
$xmlstr = <<<XML
<boxb>
   <ad type="agnostic_template">
      <url><![CDATA[http://ads.cookie.com/8/redir/1db04901-225e-11e4-86f3-bc305bf4914b/0/632361]]></url>
      <track />
      <content>
         <VAST version="2.0">
            <Ad id="228">
               <InLine>
                  <AdSystem version="4.11.0-10">LiveRail</AdSystem>
                  <AdTitle><![CDATA[TV Overlay PNG]]></AdTitle>
                  <Description />
                  <Error><![CDATA[http://t4.liverail.com/?metric=error&erc=[ERRORCODE]&pos=1&coid=135&pid=1331&nid=1331&oid=228&olid=2281331&cid=8455&tpcid=&vid=&amid=&cc=default&pp=&vi=0&vv=&sg=&tsg=&pmu=0&pau=0&psz=0&ctx=&tctx=&coty=7&adt=0&did=&buid=&scen=&mca=&mma=&mct=0&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iab.net%2Fguidelines%2F508676%2Fdigitalvideo%2Fvast%2Fvast_xml_samples&trid=53ea9957dc20a5.06241648&bidf=0.00000&bids=0.00000&bidt=1&bidh=0&bidlaf=0&cb=6662.66.104.228.162.0&ver=1&w=&wy=&x=&y=&xy=&redirect=]]></Error>
                  <Impression id="LR"><![CDATA[http://t4.liverail.com/?metric=impression&cofl=0&flid=0&pos=1&coid=135&pid=1331&nid=1331&oid=228&olid=2281331&cid=8455&tpcid=&vid=&amid=&cc=default&pp=&vi=0&vv=&sg=&tsg=&pmu=0&pau=0&psz=0&ctx=&tctx=&coty=7&adt=0&did=&buid=&scen=&mca=&mma=&mct=0&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iab.net%2Fguidelines%2F508676%2Fdigitalvideo%2Fvast%2Fvast_xml_samples&trid=53ea9957dc20a5.06241648&bidf=0.00000&bids=0.00000&bidt=1&bidh=0&bidlaf=0&cb=6662.66.104.228.162.0&ver=1&w=&wy=&x=29&y=29&xy=9dae&z2=0.00000]]></Impression>
                  <Impression id="QC"><![CDATA[http://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel/p-d05JkuPGiy-jY.gif?r=6662]]></Impression>
                  <Impression id="CS"><![CDATA[http://b.scorecardresearch.com/p?c1=1&c2=9864668&c3=1331&c4=&c5=09]]></Impression>
                  <Impression><![CDATA[http://load.exelator.com/load/?p=104&g=440&j=0]]></Impression>
                  <Impression><![CDATA[http://navdmp.com/usr?vast=http%3A%2F%2Ft4.liverail.com%2F%3Fmetric%3Dmsync%26p%3D78]]></Impression>
                  <Impression><![CDATA[http://pixel.tapad.com/idsync/ex/receive?partner_id=LIVERAIL&partner_device_id=97838239447]]></Impression>
                  <Impression><![CDATA[http://t4.liverail.com/?metric=rsync&p=3016&redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fliverail2waycm-atl.netmng.com%2Fcm%2F%3Fredirect%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Ft4.liverail.com%252F%253Fmetric%253Dcsync%2526p%253D3016%2526s%253D(NM-UserID)]]></Impression>
                  <Impression><![CDATA[http://t4.liverail.com/?metric=rsync&p=3017&redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fm.xp1.ru4.com%2Factivity%3F_o%3D62795%26_t%3Dcm_rail]]></Impression>
                  <Impression><![CDATA[http://n.us1.dyntrk.com/adx/lr/sync_lr.php?lrid=97838239447]]></Impression>
                  <Creatives>
                     <Creative sequence="1" id="8455">
                        <NonLinearAds>
                           <NonLinear width="300" height="60">
                              <StaticResource creativeType="image/png"><![CDATA[http://cdn.liverail.com/adasset/228/8455/overlay.png]]></StaticResource>
                              <NonLinearClickThrough><![CDATA[http://t4.liverail.com/?metric=clickthru&pos=1&coid=135&pid=1331&nid=1331&oid=228&olid=2281331&cid=8455&tpcid=&vid=&amid=&cc=default&pp=&vi=0&vv=&sg=&tsg=&pmu=0&pau=0&psz=0&ctx=&tctx=&coty=7&adt=0&did=&buid=&scen=&mca=&mma=&mct=0&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iab.net%2Fguidelines%2F508676%2Fdigitalvideo%2Fvast%2Fvast_xml_samples&trid=53ea9957dc20a5.06241648&bidf=0.00000&bids=0.00000&bidt=1&bidh=0&bidlaf=0&cb=6662.66.104.228.162.0&ver=1&w=&wy=&x=&y=&xy=&redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.liverail.com]]></NonLinearClickThrough>
                           </NonLinear>
                           <TrackingEvents>
                              <Tracking event="acceptInvitation"><![CDATA[http://t4.liverail.com/?metric=accept&pos=1&coid=135&pid=1331&nid=1331&oid=228&olid=2281331&cid=8455&tpcid=&vid=&amid=&cc=default&pp=&vi=0&vv=&sg=&tsg=&pmu=0&pau=0&psz=0&ctx=&tctx=&coty=7&adt=0&did=&buid=&scen=&mca=&mma=&mct=0&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iab.net%2Fguidelines%2F508676%2Fdigitalvideo%2Fvast%2Fvast_xml_samples&trid=53ea9957dc20a5.06241648&bidf=0.00000&bids=0.00000&bidt=1&bidh=0&bidlaf=0&cb=6662.66.104.228.162.0&ver=1&w=&wy=&x=&y=&xy=]]></Tracking>
                              <Tracking event="collapse"><![CDATA[http://t4.liverail.com/?metric=minimize&pos=1&coid=135&pid=1331&nid=1331&oid=228&olid=2281331&cid=8455&tpcid=&vid=&amid=&cc=default&pp=&vi=0&vv=&sg=&tsg=&pmu=0&pau=0&psz=0&ctx=&tctx=&coty=7&adt=0&did=&buid=&scen=&mca=&mma=&mct=0&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iab.net%2Fguidelines%2F508676%2Fdigitalvideo%2Fvast%2Fvast_xml_samples&trid=53ea9957dc20a5.06241648&bidf=0.00000&bids=0.00000&bidt=1&bidh=0&bidlaf=0&cb=6662.66.104.228.162.0&ver=1&w=&wy=&x=&y=&xy=]]></Tracking>
                           </TrackingEvents>
                        </NonLinearAds>
                     </Creative>
                     <Creative sequence="1" id="8455">
                        <CompanionAds>
                           <Companion width="300" height="60">
                              <StaticResource creativeType="image/jpeg"><![CDATA[http://cdn.liverail.com/adasset/228/8455/300x60.jpg]]></StaticResource>
                              <TrackingEvents>
                                 <Tracking event="creativeView"><![CDATA[http://t4.liverail.com/?metric=companion&pos=1&coid=135&pid=1331&nid=1331&oid=228&olid=2281331&cid=8455&tpcid=&vid=&amid=&cc=default&pp=&vi=0&vv=&sg=&tsg=&pmu=0&pau=0&psz=0&ctx=&tctx=&coty=7&adt=0&did=&buid=&scen=&mca=&mma=&mct=0&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iab.net%2Fguidelines%2F508676%2Fdigitalvideo%2Fvast%2Fvast_xml_samples&trid=53ea9957dc20a5.06241648&bidf=0.00000&bids=0.00000&bidt=1&bidh=0&bidlaf=0&cb=6662.66.104.228.162.0&ver=1&w=&wy=&x=&y=&xy=]]></Tracking>
                              </TrackingEvents>
                              <CompanionClickThrough><![CDATA[http://t4.liverail.com/?metric=cclickthru&pos=1&coid=135&pid=1331&nid=1331&oid=228&olid=2281331&cid=8455&tpcid=&vid=&amid=&cc=default&pp=&vi=0&vv=&sg=&tsg=&pmu=0&pau=0&psz=0&ctx=&tctx=&coty=7&adt=0&did=&buid=&scen=&mca=&mma=&mct=0&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iab.net%2Fguidelines%2F508676%2Fdigitalvideo%2Fvast%2Fvast_xml_samples&trid=53ea9957dc20a5.06241648&bidf=0.00000&bids=0.00000&bidt=1&bidh=0&bidlaf=0&cb=6662.66.104.228.162.0&ver=1&w=&wy=&x=&y=&xy=&redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.liverail.com]]></CompanionClickThrough>
                           </Companion>
                           <Companion width="300" height="250">
                              <StaticResource creativeType="image/jpeg"><![CDATA[http://cdn.liverail.com/adasset/228/8455/300x250.jpg]]></StaticResource>
                              <TrackingEvents>
                                 <Tracking event="creativeView"><![CDATA[http://t4.liverail.com/?metric=companion&pos=1&coid=135&pid=1331&nid=1331&oid=228&olid=2281331&cid=8455&tpcid=&vid=&amid=&cc=default&pp=&vi=0&vv=&sg=&tsg=&pmu=0&pau=0&psz=0&ctx=&tctx=&coty=7&adt=0&did=&buid=&scen=&mca=&mma=&mct=0&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iab.net%2Fguidelines%2F508676%2Fdigitalvideo%2Fvast%2Fvast_xml_samples&trid=53ea9957dc20a5.06241648&bidf=0.00000&bids=0.00000&bidt=1&bidh=0&bidlaf=0&cb=6662.66.104.228.162.0&ver=1&w=&wy=&x=&y=&xy=]]></Tracking>
                              </TrackingEvents>
                              <CompanionClickThrough><![CDATA[http://t4.liverail.com/?metric=cclickthru&pos=1&coid=135&pid=1331&nid=1331&oid=228&olid=2281331&cid=8455&tpcid=&vid=&amid=&cc=default&pp=&vi=0&vv=&sg=&tsg=&pmu=0&pau=0&psz=0&ctx=&tctx=&coty=7&adt=0&did=&buid=&scen=&mca=&mma=&mct=0&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iab.net%2Fguidelines%2F508676%2Fdigitalvideo%2Fvast%2Fvast_xml_samples&trid=53ea9957dc20a5.06241648&bidf=0.00000&bids=0.00000&bidt=1&bidh=0&bidlaf=0&cb=6662.66.104.228.162.0&ver=1&w=&wy=&x=&y=&xy=&redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.liverail.com]]></CompanionClickThrough>
                           </Companion>
                        </CompanionAds>
                     </Creative>
                  </Creatives>
                  <Extensions />
               </InLine>
            </Ad>
         </VAST>
         <!--  321 US_NEWJERSEY_NEWYORK_METUCHEN 08840  -->
      </content>
   </ad>
</boxb>
XML;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the XML-data, use [asXML()](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php),

```
echo $boxb->ad[0]->content->asXML();
```

---

And if you want to create your own XML document, you could use for example,

```
$myXML = new SimpleXMLElement($boxb->ad[0]->content->asXML());
echo $myXML->asXML();
```

Which would echo,

```
<!--?xml version="1.0"?-->
<content>
    ...
</content>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
include 'boxb.php';
// Load string and parse as XML
$boxb = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);
// Extract "content" element from loaded XML
$content = $boxb->ad->content;
// Convert extracted info into XML
$new_xml = $content->asXML();
// Send a header tag to the browser, stating that this info is XML
header('Content-type: application/XML');
// Print the actual XML
echo $new_xml;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks you. This is extremely helpful. How would one remove the <content> element, but keep all of the inner data to form a new structure? Would this require re-defining parent/children?